# Is it safe to use IsWindow(hWnd) to check if a window has closed?

Tags: winapi

Or can a new window be assigned the same hWnd by the OS in the time between the window closing and my code checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe because window handles are recycled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to use handles that have been destroyed.

Instead you could check if the window exists by looking for a class name.

Comment: I assume you're saying you could check if the window exists with ::IsWindow(), and then check its class name. But you can't, because it might be a new window of the same class, with a recycled window handle.

Comment: But what to do if you have to work with foreign windows?